# Large degree polynomial function

Tags: polynomials

How does one solve for $x$ in a polynomial of the form
$ax^{n} + bx^{\left(n - 1\right)} + c = 0$, given that $n$ is a larger number ?. For example:

$\displaystyle x^{100} - 3x^{99} + 1 = 0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please give more context to this question, so people can give you appropriate answers.  Is there a specific polynomial you are interested in?  Are you looking for exact solutions or numerical ones?  Are you only interested in real solutions, or do you want the complex ones, too?  What have you tried?

Comment: For example: x^100-3x^99+1=0. I need both real and complex solutions.

Comment: Please add the context to the body of your question.  Many people browsing questions will vote to close a question with no more context than this, without looking at the comments.  Also, you ought to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your posts more readable.  Look at how I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks...I have tried downloading the mathjax but it wasn't successful.

Comment: You don't need to download MathJax.  You just put formatting commands in the text.  For example `$x^{100}-3x^{99}+1=0$` is displayed as $x^{100}-3x^{99}+1=0$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand the question, but this is easy with a computer, assuming you want numerical values.  I wrote a python script to do this.  (Annoyingly, numpy expects the leading coefficient $x^k$ of a polynomial of degre $n$ to be at index $n-k.$)

```
import numpy as np

p = np.zeros((101))
p[0]=1
p[1]=-3
p[100]=1
roots = np.roots(p)
for idx, root in enumerate(roots):
    print(idx, root)
```

produces this output instantaneously:

```
0 (3.000000000000001+0j)
1 (-0.7364491456451218+0.6565561896636651j)
2 (-0.7364491456451218-0.6565561896636651j)
3 (-0.7764559201902995+0.6085861156452325j)
4 (-0.7764559201902995-0.6085861156452325j)
5 (-0.8133485650308432+0.5581912452828626j)
6 (-0.8133485650308432-0.5581912452828626j)
7 (-0.6934865839515425+0.701909773950447j)
8 (-0.6934865839515425-0.701909773950447j)
9 (-0.8469810844038753+0.5055727935082724j)
10 (-0.8469810844038753-0.5055727935082724j)
11 (-0.8772204006792861+0.4509407077743689j)
12 (-0.8772204006792861-0.4509407077743689j)
13 (-0.647738305184038+0.7444654479736014j)
14 (-0.647738305184038-0.7444654479736014j)
15 (-0.9039468754197537+0.39451284443370066j)
16 (-0.9039468754197537-0.39451284443370066j)
17 (-0.5993854422724829+0.7840527747018899j)
18 (-0.5993854422724829-0.7840527747018899j)
19 (-0.9270547780297581+0.3365141137728261j)
20 (-0.9270547780297581-0.3365141137728261j)
21 (-0.548619483695713+0.8205129677981756j)
22 (-0.548619483695713-0.8205129677981756j)
23 (-0.9464527000806124+0.2771755970853744j)
24 (-0.9464527000806124-0.2771755970853744j)
25 (-0.4956415264634955+0.8536995127614468j)
26 (-0.4956415264634955-0.8536995127614468j)
27 (-0.4406614924968664+0.8834787396172576j)
28 (-0.4406614924968664-0.8834787396172576j)
29 (-0.9620639136235793+0.21673363928004163j)
30 (-0.9620639136235793-0.21673363928004163j)
31 (-0.38389731168552527+0.909730344970996j)
32 (-0.38389731168552527-0.909730344970996j)
33 (-0.3255740750583158+0.9323478614682946j)
34 (-0.3255740750583158-0.9323478614682946j)
35 (0.7577303192949743+0.6394431221673114j)
36 (0.7577303192949743-0.6394431221673114j)
37 (0.7970347431023204+0.590099961131214j)
38 (0.7970347431023204-0.590099961131214j)
39 (0.7153872255455767+0.6861568685320916j)
40 (0.7153872255455767-0.6861568685320916j)
41 (0.8331341618753201+0.5383229631320452j)
42 (0.8331341618753201-0.5383229631320452j)
43 (0.6701830619131026+0.7300572029385581j)
44 (0.6701830619131026-0.7300572029385581j)
45 (0.8658742980131764+0.48431875063231544j)
46 (0.8658742980131764-0.48431875063231544j)
47 (0.6223059154766839+0.7709722084480215j)
48 (0.6223059154766839-0.7709722084480215j)
49 (0.5719535879849889+0.8087425205066434j)
50 (0.5719535879849889-0.8087425205066434j)
51 (0.8951137460294047+0.4283044061929457j)
52 (0.8951137460294047-0.4283044061929457j)
53 (0.5193328204049903+0.8432217744454027j)
54 (0.5193328204049903-0.8432217744454027j)
55 (0.9207248128533412+0.3705068199042141j)
56 (0.9207248128533412-0.3705068199042141j)
57 (0.46465850700695943+0.8742770284347632j)
58 (0.46465850700695943-0.8742770284347632j)
59 (0.9425943804458727+0.31116194515065604j)
60 (0.9425943804458727-0.31116194515065604j)
61 (-0.2659231616491491+0.9512390729535296j)
62 (-0.2659231616491491-0.9512390729535296j)
63 (0.4081528934442288+0.9017891596220862j)
64 (0.4081528934442288-0.9017891596220862j)
65 (0.9606247774115534+0.2505139365561644j)
66 (0.9606247774115534-0.2505139365561644j)
67 (0.9747346342048573+0.1888141457593689j)
68 (0.9747346342048573-0.1888141457593689j)
69 (0.35004475520869627+0.9256532298451866j)
70 (0.35004475520869627-0.9256532298451866j)
71 (-0.20518134277364738+0.966326373881672j)
72 (-0.20518134277364738-0.966326373881672j)
73 (0.2905685546336416+0.9457788166930109j)
74 (0.2905685546336416-0.9457788166930109j)
75 (0.9848596842823707+0.1263199581194814j)
76 (0.9848596842823707-0.1263199581194814j)
77 (-0.9738266720335937+0.15542892061869676j)
78 (-0.9738266720335937-0.15542892061869676j)
79 (0.2299635761582389+0.9620903055655939j)
80 (0.2299635761582389-0.9620903055655939j)
81 (-0.14358986755051278+0.977547071822796j)
82 (-0.14358986755051278-0.977547071822796j)
83 (0.1684730408262214+0.9745271385958778j)
84 (0.1684730408262214-0.9745271385958778j)
85 (0.9909534640600726+0.06329346693748208j)
86 (0.9909534640600726-0.06329346693748208j)
87 (0.9929878610066416+0j)
88 (-0.9816944521616785+0.09350551126383294j)
89 (-0.9816944521616785-0.09350551126383294j)
90 (0.10634320197349573+0.9830440167028471j)
91 (0.10634320197349573-0.9830440167028471j)
92 (-0.08139353360287407+0.9848536322040496j)
93 (-0.08139353360287407-0.9848536322040496j)
94 (0.043822424798379056+0.987611051554128j)
95 (0.043822424798379056-0.987611051554128j)
96 (-0.01883974695583218+0.9882138647642805j)
97 (-0.01883974695583218-0.9882138647642805j)
98 (-0.9856361368133812+0.031209912383584327j)
99 (-0.9856361368133812-0.031209912383584327j)
```

Is there some reason that this isn't good enough?